# Python: Errormessage: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, conditional-statements, isnull

I am calling the following function with parameters. The parameter are keys for some specific Dataframes, stored in a dictionary called: iNms

My Function currently looks like this:
[function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAeWJ.jpg)

But I get the following error message:
[fehler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SF81p.jpg)

When I print the left side i get "0" and from the right side i get a "False"
I think therefore it doesnt work.
I try already to convert the condition of the right side, but the error still is there.

Do you have some hints for me?
I am completly new in python (1-2 weeks) have only some theoretical knowledge, so i try to figure out my problem myself to have learning experience.

**Now with my code and error message as txt**
**On the first attempt, I tried this:**

```py
def check_missing_values(name):
    if name in iNms:
        if  iNms[name].iloc[:,[0]].isnull().sum() == 0 and len(name)<8:
            print('hurra')
            with open('Log.txt','a') as w:
                    w.write('\n{}\t\t\tKeine fehlenden Primärschlüssel\tOK'.format(name))
        elif iNms[name].iloc[:,[0]].isnull().sum() == 0 and 18>=len(name)>=8:
            print('hurra2')
            with open('Log.txt','a') as w:
                    w.write('\n{}\t\tKeine fehlenden Primärschlüssel\tOK'.format(name))   
        elif iNms[name].iloc[:,[0]].isnull().sum() != 0 and len(name)<8:
            print('hurra3')
            with open('Log.txt','a') as w:
                    w.write('\n{}\t\t\tEinige oder mehrere Primärschlüssel fehlen. Nicht OK. Nacharbeiten!'.format(name))   
        elif iNms[name].iloc[:,[0]].isnull().sum() !=0 and 18>=len(name)>=8:
            print('hurra4')
            with open('Log.txt','a') as w:
                    w.write('\n{}\t\tEinige oder mehrere Primärschlüssel fehlen. Nicht OK. Nacharbeiten!'.format(name))   
    else:
        with open('Log.txt','a') as w:
            if len(name)<17:
                w.write('\n{}\t\tnicht angeliefert'.format(name))
            else:
                w.write('\n{}\tnicht angeliefert'.format(name))
                
                
print('Left side:',iNms['transaction'].iloc[:,[2]].isnull().sum())
print('Left side:',type(iNms['transaction'].iloc[:,[2]].isnull().sum()))
print('Right side:',len('transaction')<8)
print('Right side:',type(len('transaction')<8))
```

**My second attempt**

```py
def check_missing_values(name):
    if name in iNms:
        if  (iNms[name].iloc[:,[0]].isnull().sum() == 0) & (len(name)<8):
            print('hurra')
            with open('Log.txt','a') as w:
                    w.write('\n{}\t\t\tKeine fehlenden Primärschlüssel\tOK'.format(name))
        elif (iNms[name].iloc[:,[0]].isnull().sum() == 0) & (18>=len(name)>=8):
            print('hurra2')
            with open('Log.txt','a') as w:
                    w.write('\n{}\t\tKeine fehlenden Primärschlüssel\tOK'.format(name))   
        elif (iNms[name].iloc[:,[0]].isnull().sum() != 0) & (len(name)<8):
            print('hurra3')
            with open('Log.txt','a') as w:
                    w.write('\n{}\t\t\tEinige oder mehrere Primärschlüssel fehlen. Nicht OK. Nacharbeiten!'.format(name))   
        elif (iNms[name].iloc[:,[0]].isnull().sum() !=0) & (18>=len(name)>=8):
            print('hurra4')
            with open('Log.txt','a') as w:
                    w.write('\n{}\t\tEinige oder mehrere Primärschlüssel fehlen. Nicht OK. Nacharbeiten!'.format(name))   
    else:
        with open('Log.txt','a') as w:
            if len(name)<17:
                w.write('\n{}\t\tnicht angeliefert'.format(name))
            else:
                w.write('\n{}\tnicht angeliefert'.format(name))

print('Left side:',iNms['transaction'].iloc[:,[2]].isnull().sum())
print('Left side:',type(iNms['transaction'].iloc[:,[2]].isnull().sum()))
print('Right side:',len('transaction')<8)
print('Right side:',type(len('transaction')<8))
```

**I get the following error message:**

```py
Left side: transaction_ts    0
dtype: int64
Left side: <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
Right side: False
Right side: <class 'bool'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tayfunuenver/Documents/Python/Parser_2.py", line 217, in <module>
    check_missing_values('customer')
  File "/home/tayfunuenver/Documents/Python/Parser_2.py", line 174, in check_missing_values
    if  iNms[name].iloc[:,[0]].isnull().sum() == 0 and len(name)<8:
  File "/home/tayfunuenver/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1330, in __nonzero__
    f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: Please paste your function and the full error message as text. Pasting images makes it harder for people to copy-paste and reproduce your problem.

Comment: Ok you are right. I will do it when i am back at home.

Comment: I have now updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message points out - your error is in this line -

`if  iNms[name].iloc[:,[0]].isnull().sum() == 0 and len(name)<8:`

If you look closely, you are using and on two separate types of objects here -

`iNms[name].iloc[:,[0]].isnull().sum() == 0` is the first object, and it returns a `pd.Series`, while the second object `len(name) < 8` is a boolean.

So Python, and Pandas, are helpfully telling you that evaluating something like

`pd.Series([True, True, False]) and True` is ambiguous.

For your case - there are a couple of solutions -

### 1

Either use the `bool()` from the series, as your series only has 1 value -

`(df.iloc[:, [0]].isnull().sum() == 0).bool() and (len(name) < 8)`

### 2

Or use the `&` operator -

`(df.iloc[:, [0]].isnull().sum() == 0) & (len(name) < 8)`

Comment: I have now tried your solution. The first one works for me the second one not but i will try it again, maybe i made a typo.

Answer (score 2):

@Mortz
I have now tried your solution. The first one works for me the second one not but i will try it again, maybe i made a typo. Thank your for your help.

I found a third solution, which I want to share with this community.
In the same time I have shortened my code a bit.
Now it looks like this:

```
def check_missing_values(name):
    
    if name in iNms:
        erstespalte_insight = iNms[name].iloc[:,[0]]
        summiere_nullwerte = erstespalte_insight.isnull().sum().sum()
        if  summiere_nullwerte == 0 and len(name)<8:
            print('hurra')
            with open('Log.txt','a') as w:
                    w.write('\n{}\t\t\tKeine fehlenden Primärschlüssel\tOK'.format(name))
        elif summiere_nullwerte == 0 and 18>=len(name)>=8:
            print('hurra2')
            with open('Log.txt','a') as w:
                    w.write('\n{}\t\tKeine fehlenden Primärschlüssel\tOK'.format(name))   
        elif summiere_nullwerte != 0 and len(name)<8:
            print('hurra3')
            with open('Log.txt','a') as w:
                    w.write('\n{}\t\t\tEinige oder mehrere Primärschlüssel fehlen. Nicht OK. Nacharbeiten!'.format(name))   
        elif summiere_nullwerte !=0 and 18>=len(name)>=8:
            print('hurra4')
            with open('Log.txt','a') as w:
                    w.write('\n{}\t\tEinige oder mehrere Primärschlüssel fehlen. Nicht OK. Nacharbeiten!'.format(name))   
    else:
        with open('Log.txt','a') as w:
            if len(name)<17:
                w.write('\n{}\t\tnicht angeliefert'.format(name))
            else:
                w.write('\n{}\tnicht angeliefert'.format(name))


And the output on the terminal:
```

```
tayfunuenver@vmOperations1:~/Documents/Python$ /usr/bin/python3 /home/tayfunuenver/Documents/Python/Parser_2.py
1.Prüfung: ZIP-File erfüllt die Anforderungen des Datums:       2021-09-30      OK


hurra2
hurra
hurra4
hurra
```

Comment: Great - if I understood correctly, you are now "collapsing" the `Series` into a single integer value which can be used with `and`

Comment: Yes this is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is that for the comparison

```
iNms[name].iloc[:,[0]].isnull().sum() == 0
```

you are apparently comparing a Series (the return-value of the `sum()`-function) with an integer. To make sure that the result of `sum()` is always possible to compare to the integer `0`, you can write

```
int(iNms[name].iloc[:,[0]].isnull().sum()) == 0
```

Comment: I will try this also out. Thank you for your answer.